# How to reduce the volume of traces in Logic Apps Standard

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-logic-app-standard

I'm using the Logic Apps Standard and Application Insights.
Each time a Logic Apps Standard Workflow is triggered, it generates a lot of traces and I want to reduce those traces and avoid having too much data ingestion generated into Application Insights.

I first want to remove traces coming from the storage account that is used behind the scene by the Logic App.

I tried to change the content of the host.json file in order to set this:
"logLevel": {
"default": "Information",
"Host.Results": "Error"
}

Unfortunately, I'm still having a lot of traces as if the host.json file is ignored.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to reduce those traces and avoid having too much data ingestion generated into Application Insights.

You cannot reduce the trace logs. The only possible way is either you have to **enable or disable the trace logs** in ***Application Insights***.

In your **host.json** file you keep **logLevel**  has **`"default": "Information"`** and **`"Host.Results": "Error"`**  which means by **`default`** the logic app function collect the **`trace information`**

To **avoid the trace level logs you have to keep the higher level logging**. Refer [log level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#configure-log-levels)

If you don't want the trace information you have to keep your **`host.json`** file like below

```
"logLevel": {
      "default": "Error",
      "Host.Results": "Error"
      }
```